# Fold text and images in markdown output

Tags: r, knitr

I'm trying to create an `HTML` file using `knitr` package in `R`. This sounds simple but I can't seem to find a solution to this:

I would like to be able to fold the text and images in my output having the little `+` buttons. Would anybody happen to have an idea of how do I do that?

For example, I'd like to fold the following image with some text in the next line:

````
```{r,echo=FALSE,warning=FALSE}
p <- ggplot(sumRevenue, aes(x=Date, y=Revenue, fill=clusters)) + scale_x_date(breaks=x_breaks, labels=x_labels) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "fill",alpha=0.6) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format()) + xlab('') +
  ggtitle('Physical filing percent spread for segments') + theme_bw() + ylab('Percent Spread') +
  theme(axis.text.y=element_text(hjust=0, angle=0), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(hjust=1, angle=45),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x=element_line(color='grey90',linetype='dashed'),
        panel.grid.major.y=element_line(color='grey90',linetype='dashed'),
        plot.title=element_text(size=20),
        axis.text=element_text(size=10),
        legend.key=element_blank(),
        legend.title=element_blank()) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#a6cee3","#1f78b4","#b2df8a")) 
p
```
Some text here
````

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want a "show more"-style button? If so, I don't think Rmarkdown supports that.

Comment: IIRC the knitrBootstrap package produces something similar to your description

Comment: maybe https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/fold-show.html is some help